# Android widget select type/size like in HTC Sense

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to change android:minWidth and android:minHeight in widget configuration activity.
I want to be able to give user a selection of different sizes/types like in htc sense widgets, how did they succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different sizes in one menu entry are not possible. Thats a sense/custom launcher specific feature. The only exception is Honeycomb, you can have resizable widgets there.

What you can do is multiple types of widgets from one menu entry, as long as they are the same size. Use a configuration activity to select the type, remember it (e.g. in the `SharedPreferences`) and then set the layout in your `RemoteViews` when updating the widgets accordingly. You can use the `appWidgetId` as an identifier to remember which instance has which layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think vanilla Android can do what your after.
I suspect sense has a custom Launcher

However you could try using the `AppWidgetProviderInfo` class, something like the following:

```
AppWidgetProviderInfo widget_info = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
widget_info.minWidth = 72;
widget_info.minHeight = 72;
```

Obviously you'd set values as per your the users choice in the widget configuration activity ((number of cols or rows * 74) - 2)
I'm also not entirely sure if changes to those fields persist.

Sorry for the uncertainty, hopefully this will at least give you something to try.

Comment: Nope this could not be done, but thanks anyway, it was a good try.